# Methods in Java API for Lotus Notes returns Vector and not ArrayList

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, lotus-notes

If I need to retrieve the value of a field, I will need to use this function

```
public java.util.Vector getItemValue(String name) throws NotesException
```

Well, this method like any others in the Lotus Notes Java API returns `Vector` objects. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386288/1893936) is explained that Vector is obsolete. But this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386699/1893936) on the same question make me think that the using of Vector maybe was necessary.

> Although Enumerations are faster, they don't check if the collection
>   was modified during iteration, which can cause issues, and given that
>   Vector might be chosen for its syncronization - with the attendant
>   access from multiple threads, this makes it a particularly pernicious
>   problem.

When we use the Lotus Notes Java API, is there any problem if we convert the resulting `Vector` objects to `ArrayList` objects?

```
Vector<String> vector = (Vector<String>) doc.getItemValue("somefield");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(vector);
```

Or, in general, isn't this conversion recommended?

**EDIT:** Just in case, *I don't want/need to use `Vector` objects*, but the methods from the Lotus Notes Java API always return that. So, I have two options: (1) always convert the `Vector` objects to `ArrayList` or any other better option, or (2) just use `Vector` objects.

In short, my doubt is: is it safe to convert Vector objects to ArrayList in situations like this?

Comment: Where in the Javadoc for [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/InetAddress.html) does it say it is deprecated? It may be _considered obsolete_ by some, but deprecated it isn't. Please use proper terminology.

Comment: @Lolo Fixed. Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the Vector into a more modern Collection. But You have to ensure, that you don't use Java 7 Features or classes.

As far as I know, IBM Notes still uses an IBM Java 6 VM.

And generics are a litte dangerous, because I am not sure, that every Item, which is returned by `getItemValue()` in the Vector is a String.

**Update**

I would prefer, to use the `Vector` because thats the way, the API works.

In fact the IBM Notes / Domino API is some kind of horrible. There is a [wrapper for the API from openNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API).

Comment: Yes, you're rigth about the Java version used in Lotus Domino/Notes. Just to be sure to not use features not supported by Notes, I installed only the JRE 6... Whoa! I just seen your update. That's what I looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use deprecated `Vector`s. They're  notoriously slow.

If you need a synchronised list, you can turn any list into a synchronised version with

```
syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

Comment: Notes itself uses Vector (without Generics). It's that bad. So using a List ist not possible, due to the API.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach yes, I meant convert them to lists and then use the lists, as OP suggests, and then use a synchronised version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

[`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)s have been deprecated for ages. Unless you particularly need it's thread safety, just use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - it'll be faster. And even if you do require your collection to be thread safe, there are better choices in modern JDKs, such as the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: IBM installs an IBM Java6 VM, so newer classes or features are out of reach.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach `CopyOnWriteArrayList` has been available since java 5. I've updated all the links in my answer to point to Java 5's documentation in order to remove these concerns.